# How to write nested for loop in omnet?

Tags: omnet++

I'm trying to write a nested for loop in OMNeT++ to set connections for my modules labeled X and Y. I want to connect each X to every single Y I have. For example, I have 4 X and 8 Y. I want to connect the output of each X to every single Y's input dynamically.

I am getting the error:

> unexpected NAME, expecting IF or FOR

They are radio gates. 
My code is as follows:

**NED FILE**

```
connections:
        for i=0..sizeof(x), j=0..sizeof(y) do
            x[i].upperLayerIn --> y[i].upperLayerOut;
        endfor;
```

I have also tried that code:

```
connections:
        for i=0..sizeof(sat), j=0..sizeof(stat){
            sat[i].upperLayerIn --> stat[i].upperLayerOut;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

- The syntax of for loop in NED is described in [OMNeT++ manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-ref:connection-groups).
- Take care that NED syntax is case-sensitive: you have mentioned in your question X and Y as module's name (capital letters), but in the code you have used x and y (lower case).

Assuming that the definition of a node looks like:

```
simple Node {
  gates:
    output upperLayerOut[];
    input upperLayerIn[];
}
```

the corrected code should be:

```
network Net {
  submodules:
      x[3] : Node;
      y[3] : Node;
 connections allowunconnected:
    for i=0..sizeof(x)-1, for j=0..sizeof(y)-1 {
        x[i].upperLayerOut++ --> y[j].upperLayerIn++;
        x[i].upperLayerIn++ <-- y[j].upperLayerOut++;
    }
}
```